# Fprintf not printing

Tags: c, file, printf

I've been trying to do file excercises in C but when I run programs from the professor or tutorials (which should work), the file always comes out blank. Is there a solution to this?

My computer is pretty old, but it can still run various programs, I don't undersand why it doesn't work with files

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*program that prints on a file your shopping list*/
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp= fopen("Shopping list.txt", "w");
    int end= 0; //have you finished writing the articles
    char article[80];   //the article you want to buy
    int n;      //quantity

    while(!end){
        printf("What do you need to buy? ");
        fgets(article, 80, stdin);
        article[strlen(article)- 1]= '\0';
        fprintf(fp, "%s ", article);

        printf("How much of it? ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        fprintf(fp, "%d\n", n);

        printf("Are you done? (1= Yes, 0= No) ");
        scanf("%d%*c", &end);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

It should print out on the file (which is created and remains empty) your input. There is no error message

Comment: Why I run the program with input “abc”, “3”, and “1”, the result is a file named “Shopping list.txt” is created with contents “abc 3”. You should show the exact input you are providing and the contents of “Shopping list.txt” after the program runs.

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) after calling `fopen` check if `fp == 0` meaning the file couldn't be opened for some reason. 2) Change the relative path "Shopping list.txt" to an absolute path, e.g. "c:\\temp\\shopping list.txt" or "/tmp/shopping_list.txt" etc., to avoid confusion of the code runs out of some temporary folder (I've seen a lot of VS users getting tricked by this)

Comment: The return value of `scanf` and friends should never be ignored.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I've tried with simpler programs but it still doesn't print out anything

Comment: @MortenJensen you're right, I'll check and verify

Comment: I would bet a coin that you are using an IDE. If it is true, the file has probably be created and populated but not in the directory that your are looking. Try to search for it throughout all the disk, or add `printf("%s\n", getcwd());` as first instruction in `main` to know where that *@!# file is.

Comment: @FilippoBiancone: I did not suggest a simpler program. I asked for the **exact input** you are supplying to the program.

Comment: @MortenJensen: The question reports the file is created but remains empty. That assertion is not consistent with the `fopen` failing, although it could be a mistaken report.

Comment: @EricPostpischil good point, 1) was mostly just my paranoia. I think it's more likely case 2) that the file is created somewhere else. However that is also not consistent with an empty file(?), so maybe OP has lost track of events while debugging  - I know I do sometimes :)

Comment: I've resolved the problem. It was simply that, during fopen, I had to specify the absolute path. It has filled the file. Thank you all

Comment: @FilippoBiancone congrats :) If you post the solution as an answer, you can mark your own answer as the accepted solution and get a few points (you solved the problem, so that's totally okay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved the problem by simply specifying the absolute path in fopen

Comment: You should add lots of error checking to this program. Every operation you call that can return success or failure should be checked. It will make debugging so much easier.

Comment: It's a basic exam, we don't have to do that for now luckly xD

Comment: If you'd rather figure out the problem two months later, I guess.